# Pixel counting in Swift 3

Tags: swift, pixel, cgimage

I have an app that counts pixels of images to get relative areas of five colours in an image. The updated version to Swift 3, works with a declared image that is in the supporting files of the app but not with a variable image that comes from documents directory . What am I missing?

This version works:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ComputeAreaViewController: UIViewController {

var redValue: String!
var blueValue: String!
var greenValue: String!
var whiteValue: String!
var yellowValue: String!
var totalValue: String!

//var image: UIImage!

let image = UIImage(named: "test_image.png")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /*
    let fm = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in:      .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("tmp.png")
    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: myurl.path)!
     */

    view.layer.contents = image.cgImage!

    computeArea()
}

func classifyPixel( _ r: UInt8, _ g: UInt8, _ b: UInt8, _ coverRed:   inout UInt, _ coverGreen: inout UInt, _ coverYellow: inout UInt, _ coverBlue: inout UInt, _ coverWhite: inout UInt ) {
    if r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0 { coverRed += 1 }
    if r == 0 && g == 255 && b == 0 { coverGreen += 1 }
    if r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 0 { coverYellow += 1 }
    if r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 255 { coverBlue += 1 }
    if r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255 { coverWhite += 1 }
}

func computeArea() {

    var coverRed: UInt = 0
    var coverGreen: UInt = 0
    var coverYellow: UInt = 0
    var coverBlue: UInt = 0
    var coverWhite: UInt = 0
    var coverTotal = 0

    let imageWidth = Int(image.size.width)
    let imageHeight = Int(image.size.height)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth

    let bufferSize = bytesPerRow * imageHeight
    var bytesPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate( bytes: bufferSize, alignedTo: 1 )
    let bytesPointerSaved = bytesPointer

    if let bitmapContext = CGContext( data: bytesPointer, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue ) {

        bitmapContext.draw( (image.cgImage!), in: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight ), byTiling: false )

        for _ in 0..<imageHeight {
            for _ in 0..<imageWidth {
                var r: UInt8 = 0, g: UInt8 = 0, b: UInt8 = 0
                r = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 1
                g = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 1
                b = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 2
                classifyPixel( r, g, b, &coverRed, &coverGreen, &coverYellow, &coverBlue, &coverWhite )
                coverTotal += 1
            }
        }

    } else {
        print( #file + " " + #function + " failed to create bitmap context ")
    }
    bytesPointerSaved.deallocate( bytes: bufferSize, alignedTo: 1 )
    let fTotal = Float( coverTotal )
    print( "coverRed: \(100.0*Float(coverRed)/fTotal), coverGreen: \   (100.0*Float(coverGreen)/fTotal), coverYellow: \(100.0*Float(coverYellow)/fTotal), coverBlue: \(100.0*Float(coverBlue)/fTotal), coverWhite: \(100.0*Float(coverWhite)/fTotal), coverTotal: \(coverTotal), #ofPixels: \(bufferSize/bytesPerPixel)" )

    greenValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverGreen)/fTotal))
    yellowValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverYellow)/fTotal))
    redValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverRed)/fTotal))
    blueValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverBlue)/fTotal))
    whiteValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverWhite)/fTotal))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "computeResult" {

        let areaController = segue.destination as! AreaPercentViewController
        areaController.redValue = redValue
        areaController.blueValue = blueValue
        areaController.greenValue = greenValue
        areaController.whiteValue = whiteValue
        areaController.yellowValue = yellowValue
        areaController.totalValue = totalValue
    }
}
}
```

This version does not work:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ComputeAreaViewController: UIViewController {

var redValue: String!
var blueValue: String!
var greenValue: String!
var whiteValue: String!
var yellowValue: String!
var totalValue: String!

var image: UIImage!

//let image = UIImage(named: "test_image.png")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fm = FileManager.default
    let docsurl = try! fm.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("tmp.png")
    image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: myurl.path)!

    view.layer.contents = image.cgImage!

    computeArea()
}

func classifyPixel( _ r: UInt8, _ g: UInt8, _ b: UInt8, _ coverRed: inout UInt, _ coverGreen: inout UInt, _ coverYellow: inout UInt, _ coverBlue: inout UInt, _ coverWhite: inout UInt ) {
    if r == 255 && g == 0 && b == 0 { coverRed += 1 }
    if r == 0 && g == 255 && b == 0 { coverGreen += 1 }
    if r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 0 { coverYellow += 1 }
    if r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 255 { coverBlue += 1 }
    if r == 255 && g == 255 && b == 255 { coverWhite += 1 }
}

func computeArea() {

    var coverRed: UInt = 0
    var coverGreen: UInt = 0
    var coverYellow: UInt = 0
    var coverBlue: UInt = 0
    var coverWhite: UInt = 0
    var coverTotal = 0

    let imageWidth = Int(image.size.width)
    let imageHeight = Int(image.size.height)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * imageWidth

    let bufferSize = bytesPerRow * imageHeight
    var bytesPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate( bytes: bufferSize, alignedTo: 1 )
    let bytesPointerSaved = bytesPointer

    if let bitmapContext = CGContext( data: bytesPointer, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue ) {

        bitmapContext.draw( (image.cgImage!), in: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight ), byTiling: false )

        for _ in 0..<imageHeight {
            for _ in 0..<imageWidth {
                var r: UInt8 = 0, g: UInt8 = 0, b: UInt8 = 0
                r = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 1
                g = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 1
                b = bytesPointer.load( as: UInt8.self )
                bytesPointer += 2
                classifyPixel( r, g, b, &coverRed, &coverGreen, &coverYellow, &coverBlue, &coverWhite )
                coverTotal += 1
            }
        }

    } else {
        print( #file + " " + #function + " failed to create bitmap context ")
    }
    bytesPointerSaved.deallocate( bytes: bufferSize, alignedTo: 1 )
    let fTotal = Float( coverTotal )
    print( "coverRed: \(100.0*Float(coverRed)/fTotal), coverGreen: \(100.0*Float(coverGreen)/fTotal), coverYellow: \(100.0*Float(coverYellow)/fTotal), coverBlue: \(100.0*Float(coverBlue)/fTotal), coverWhite: \(100.0*Float(coverWhite)/fTotal), coverTotal: \(coverTotal), #ofPixels: \(bufferSize/bytesPerPixel)" )

    greenValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverGreen)/fTotal))
    yellowValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverYellow)/fTotal))
    redValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverRed)/fTotal))
    blueValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverBlue)/fTotal))
    whiteValue = String(describing: (100.0*Float(coverWhite)/fTotal))
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "computeResult" {

        let areaController = segue.destination as! AreaPercentViewController
        areaController.redValue = redValue
        areaController.blueValue = blueValue
        areaController.greenValue = greenValue
        areaController.whiteValue = whiteValue
        areaController.yellowValue = yellowValue
        areaController.totalValue = totalValue
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly in the `ComputeAreaViewController` class doesn't work? It would be helpful if we knew exactly what it was that doesn't work

Comment: Sincere question - have you tried this with a HD image? A large image? Any performance issues? Any thoughts on using CIAreaHistogram instead?

Comment: With the version that includes " let image = UIImage(named: "test-image.png") the computeArea function works perfectly and the pixels are counted giving a result. With the "var image: UIImage!" version the image is obtained from documents directory and displayed, but the computeArea function does not work and all I get is zeros. I suspect it has something to do with "view.layer.contents = image:cgImage!"

Comment: Regarding HD image, I have not yet reached the stage of comparing performance. I am still at the stage of getting things to work. But, my test image is 524288 pixels and the drawn image that is grabbed from the documents directory is 153600 pixels, so when it does work I can look at any differences in performance. I am looking at the various CI methods to see if there is not a better way to accomplish the goal.

Comment: I have narrowed things down. The issue seems to be all about the "image". When I use the test_image which comes from the mainBundle, everything is fine and the pixels are counted. But when I pass an image from the previous view, which is a drawn image, the image is displayed, but the pixels are not counted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the alpha channel of the image being passed. It was less than 1.0, resetting it to 1.0 fixed the counting issue.